# Вытащить все нужные ссылки Python

Tags: python

Час добрый
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно вытащить все нужные ссылки примерно из такого текста :

```
Интернет-магазин "МИР СТРУН" - http://mirstrun.ru/ В этом разборе офигенная новогодняя песня для начинающих, группы СТЕКЛОВАТА - НОВЫЙ ГОД. Разберем на гитаре разными способами. Открой описание! Аккорды и Текст ↓↓↓

Стекловата - Новый год Аккорды - https://www.4chords.ru/2017/12/akkord...

Мои Соц. Сети:
Я ВКонтакте - https://vk.com/stixatvorez
Я в Instagram - http://instagram.com/stixatvorez
Мои песни Вконтакте - https://vk.com/safronovband

В час когда зажигаются свечи.
```

Тексты берутся с описаний к видео на youtube.
Получать нужно следующие ссылки:

```
1)Телеграм https://t.me/
2)Инстаграм https://instagram.com/
3)ВК https://vk.ru/
4)Facebook https://facebook.com/
5)Если ни в одно условие не попало, но все таки есть https://, то сохранить в отдельную переменную
```

Мне предложили попробовать следующий способ, но с таким текстом он не справляется, т.к. там идет проверка конкретно ссылки на наличие нужных слов:

```
import re

url = ваша ссылка
telegram, instagram, vk, facebook, other = list(), list(), list(), list(), list()
if re.match("https://t.me/", url):
    telegram.append(url)
elif re.match("https://instagram.com/", url):
    instagram.append(url)
elif re.match("https://vk.ru/", url):
    vk.append(url)
elif re.match("https://facebook.com/", url):
    facebook.append(url)
elif re.match("https://", url):
    other.append(url)
```

Как можно его переписать чтобы он мог обрабатывать ссылки из примера выше?  Весь текст хранится в одной переменной
Или подскажите каким регулярным выражением можно вытащить все ссылки из текста, чтобы потом пройтись по ним описанным выше алгоритмом

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=python+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5+site:ru.stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt1NLBxIb1AhXlsYsKHc9cCOkQrQIoBHoECAYQBQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я написал для вас регулярное выражение. Оно вернет для вас все ссылки в одном списке.

Вот пример работы:

**Код:**

```
import re

text = '''
ЗДЕСЬ ВАШ ТЕКСТ
'''

print(re.findall(r'https?://\S+', text))
```

**Вывод:**

```
['http://mirstrun.ru/', 
 'https://www.4chords.ru/2017/12/akkord...', 
 'https://vk.com/stixatvorez', 
 'http://instagram.com/stixatvorez', 
 'https://vk.com/safronovband']
```

**Как работает это регулярное выражение?**

1. `http` - Ищем начало ссылки
2. `s?` - Квантификатор после s означает что присутствие s *необязательно*. То есть, сработает даже на `http://`.
3. `://` - Конец протокола сайта
4. `\S+` - Берем все символы которые не являються пробелами.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Спасибо за благодарность!